# Summing up only number (integer) inputs

Tags: macros

I have a custom defined command that takes six arguments separated by commas as one argument, which I then separate into multiple arguments using `\SplitArgument`. I need a to define command which sums only inputs that are numbers and leaves out any text for example "-". I've tried to define a command using package `xstring`'s `\IsInteger`, but as I need to do some math operations with the resulting number (division, multiplication) that didn't work for me. Instead of performing the operation the command "printed" for example "021 / 24". I dont know why there is an extra zero before the summed number, but i suspect it had to do something with `xstring` not taking nested commands well. Anyway I pasted a simplified version of my code down below. If anyone could help I'd be grateful.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\example}{ >{\SplitArgument{5}{,}} m}{\splitexample#1}

\NewDocumentCommand{\splitexample}{mmmmmm}{%
some text, #1, #2, #3, #4, #5, #6, some more text, value inserted by another cmd, value inserted by another cmd, the sum off all the inputs is: %insert sum command here%
}

\begin{document}
\example{1,2,3,4,5,6} %expected output: 21

\example{1, -, 2, -, 3, 4} %expected output: 10
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean just integers or floating point numbers? Could they be negative or stored in macros?

Comment: @egreg I was planning to use it just with positive integers (natural numbers) including zero and their initial values won't be stored in macros

Comment: Is there a need for `-` when no number is supplied? For example, would `\example{1, , 2, , 3, 4}` also be acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### update as per comment request

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\example[1]{\the\numexpr0\example@i{}#1,\hbox\relax}
\def\example@i#1#2{%
    \ifcase
    \ifx\hbox#2\z@\else\ifx,#2\@ne\else\ifnum9<1\string#2 \tw@\else\@M\fi\fi\fi
    % hit end, nothing to do, \relax terminates \the\numexpr
      \expandafter\@gobbletwo
    \or % hit a comma after having seen only digits in this round
      #1+0\expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \or % a digit, accumulate it
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \else % a non-digit gob to comma
      \expandafter\example@continue
    \fi
    {\example@i{}}{\example@i{#1#2}}%
}
\def\example@continue#1,{\example@i{}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\example[1]{\the\numexpr0\example@i{}#1,\hbox\relax}
\def\example@i#1#2{%
    \ifcase
    \ifx\hbox#2\z@\else\ifx,#2\@ne\else\ifnum9<1\string#2 \tw@\else\@M\fi\fi\fi
    % hit end, nothing to do, \relax terminates \the\numexpr
      \expandafter\@gobbletwo
    \or % hit a comma after having seen only digits in this round
      #1+0\expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \or % a digit, accumulate it
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \else % a non-digit gob to comma
      \expandafter\example@continue
    \fi
    {\example@i{}}{\example@i{#1#2}}%
}
\def\example@continue#1,{\example@i{}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\integerindices[1]{\expanded\integerindices@i0!{}#1,\hbox}
\def\integerindices@i#1!#2#3{%
    \ifcase
    \ifx\hbox#3\z@\else\ifx,#3\@ne\else\ifnum9<1\string#3 \tw@\else\@M\fi\fi\fi
    % hit end
      \expandafter\@firstoffour
    \or % hit a comma directly, increase index and check next one
      \expandafter\@secondoffour
    \or % a digit, dispatch to second auxiliary
      \expandafter\@thirdoffour
    \else % the item starts with a non-digit gob to comma and continue
      \expandafter\@fourthoffour
    \fi
        {{\integerindices@tocsv#2\relax}}% produce in csv format
        {\expandafter\integerindices@i\the\numexpr1+#1!{#2}}%
        {\integerindices@ii#1!{#2}}%
        {\expandafter\integerindices@continue\the\numexpr1+#1!{#2}}%
}
\def\integerindices@continue#1!#2#3,{\integerindices@i#1!{#2}}
\def\integerindices@ii#1!#2#3{%
    \ifcase
    \ifx\hbox#3\z@\else\ifx,#3\@ne\else\ifnum9<1\string#3 \tw@\else\@M\fi\fi\fi
    % hit end
      \expandafter\@firstoffour
    \or % hit a comma after having seen only digits
      \expandafter\@secondoffour
    \or % a digit, keep parsing
      \expandafter\@thirdoffour
    \else % a non-digit gob to comma
      \expandafter\@fourthoffour
    \fi
        % perennial problems of comma separated lists
        % I decided to produce the csv at very end
        {{\integerindices@tocsv#2\relax}}% convert to csv
        {\expandafter\integerindices@i\the\numexpr1+#1!{#2{#1}}}%
        {\integerindices@ii#1!{#2}}%
        {\expandafter\integerindices@continue\the\numexpr1+#1!{#2}}%
}

\long\def\@firstoffour#1#2#3#4{#1}
\long\def\@secondoffour#1#2#3#4{#2}
\long\def\@thirdoffour#1#2#3#4{#3}
\long\def\@fourthoffour#1#2#3#4{#4}

\def\integerindices@tocsv#1{\ifx\relax#1\else#1\expandafter\integerindices@tocsv@i\fi}
\def\integerindices@tocsv@i#1{\ifx\relax#1\else, #1\expandafter\integerindices@tocsv@i\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This works expandably: \example{a,,2,xyz,40}.

The list of indices starting at zero is for \verb|a,,2,xyz,40|: \integerindices{a,,2,xyz,40}.

 \edef\foo{\integerindices{1,az,32,66,;,87e,35,,,,!!!,99}}
The list of indices starting at zero for \verb|1,az,32,66,;,87e,35,,,,!!!,99| is stored in macro \verb|\foo| with meaning \texttt{\meaning\foo}.

\end{document}
```

[image: extension giving integer indices]

*edited* I have edited the code so that the comma separated list has spaces after the commas.  New screenshot:[image]

#### initial answer

I have composed this expandable solution according to specifications:

- only non-negative integers, no plus sign,
- explicit digits, not hidden in macros.

You can have arbitrarily many items.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\example[1]{\the\numexpr0\example@i{}#1,\hbox\relax}
\def\example@i#1#2{%
    \ifcase
    \ifx\hbox#2\z@\else\ifx,#2\@ne\else\ifnum9<1\string#2 \tw@\else\@M\fi\fi\fi
    % hit end, nothing to do, \relax terminates \the\numexpr
      \expandafter\@gobbletwo
    \or % hit a comma after having seen only digits in this round
      #1+0\expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \or % a digit, accumulate it
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \else % a non-digit gob to comma
      \expandafter\example@continue
    \fi
    {\example@i{}}{\example@i{#1#2}}%
}
\def\example@continue#1,{\example@i{}}
\makeatother
  

\begin{document}
This works expandably: \example{a,,2,xyz,40}.
\begin{verbatim}
This is now executed:
\ttfamily\parindent0pt
\edef\foo{\example{1,2,3,4,5,6}}% expected output: 21
\meaning\foo\par
\edef\foo{\example{1, -, 2, -, 3, 4}}% expected output: 10
\meaning\foo\par
\edef\foo{\example{a,,2,xyz,40}}% expected output: 42
\meaning\foo\par
\edef\foo{\example{1,az,32,66,;,87e,35,,,,!!!,}}% expected output: 134
\meaning\foo\par
\end{verbatim}
\ttfamily\parindent0pt
\edef\foo{\example{1,2,3,4,5,6}}%expected output: 21
\meaning\foo\par
\edef\foo{\example{1, -, 2, -, 3, 4}}% expected output: 10
\meaning\foo\par
\edef\foo{\example{a,,2,xyz,40}}% expected output: 42
\meaning\foo\par
\edef\foo{\example{1,az,32,66,;,87e,35,,,,!!!,}}% expected output: 134
\meaning\foo\par

\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{\example{,,,,45,!!,^$,&(,text,55}}
\arabic{mycounter}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

I added the counter stuff demo afterwards:

```latex
\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{\example{,,,,45,!!,^$,&(,text,55}}
\arabic{mycounter}
```

[image: again output plus a counter example]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it worked perfectly when I integrated it into my project. I have one more question. Is there a way to print a list of the arguments that are numbers? For example if I inputed the list {3, 4, 3, 4, 3, -} it would output the list {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} or with strarting with zero {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}. 
More examples: 
{-, -, -, 3, 5, -} -> {4, 5}(or {3, 4})
{1, -, 3, 7, 1, -} -> {1, 3, 4, 5}(or{0, 2, 3, 4})

Comment: @AtjovDavid updated answer

Answer (score 3):

You can have any number of items. Of course the command cannot be fully expandable.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\example}{m}
 {
  \atjov_example:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__atjov_example_items_seq
\int_new:N \l__atjov_example_sum_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \atjov_example:n
 {
  \int_zero:N \l__atjov_example_sum_int
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__atjov_example_items_seq { #1 }
  \seq_map_function:NN \l__atjov_example_items_seq \__atjov_example_do:n
  \int_use:N \l__atjov_example_sum_int
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__atjov_example_do:n
 {
  \regex_match:nnT { \A [0-9]+ \Z } { #1 }
   {% #1 is an integer
    \int_add:Nn \l__atjov_example_sum_int { #1 }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\example{1,2,3,4,5,6} %expected output: 21

\example{1, -, 2, -, 3, 4} %expected output: 10

\example{a,,2,xyz,40} % expected: 42

\end{document}
```

[image]

We split the input at commas and then test whether each item is a nonnegative integer (a sequence of digits of length at least 1); in this case we add to the specific integer variable. Finally the sum is delivered.